# How to compare if an item in a list has the same value AND position as an item in another list? Python 2.7

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

eg.

```
l1 = [a,b,c,d]
l2 = [e,b,f,g]
```

A method that would return true when it sees that b is in both l1 and l2, and in position [1] in both lists. Preferably something that I can use in a for loop so that I can compare all the items in the list.

Many thanks :)

Comment: Why not just compare the lists for equality?

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Not exactly. Ricochet_Bunny also wants to check  if 'b' is in the same position in both lists

Comment: If the lists are equal then all the elements will be in the same positions. This is how Python compares lists.

Comment: List equality is not what is asked. Equality here means that at least one element is equal in position and value. At least that is my understanding.

Comment: But if the ultimate purpose is, "so that I can compare all the items in the list", then you might as well just test for list equality: `l1 == l2`.

Comment: @unutbu When he said that, he meant so when going through a loop, he can compare each item to each other item in the other list, and if two are the same (and in the same position) it would return True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
if 'b' in l1 and 'b' in l2: # Separated both statements to prevent ValueErrors
    if l1.index('b') == l2.index('b'): 
        print 'b is in both lists and same position!'
```

Unlike Volatility's code, the length in either list doesn't matter.

The index() function gets the position of an element in a string. For example, if there was:

```
>>> mylist = ['hai', 'hello', 'hey']
>>> print mylist.index('hello')
1
```

Comment: This actually turns out to be just what I need as I want to be able to test for if an item is in both lists, and a second test to see if it is in the same position, which I can modify this code to do

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
def has_equal_element(list1, list2):
    return any(e1 == e2 for e1, e2 in zip(list1, list2))
```

This function will return `True` when at least one element has the same value and position as in the other list. This function also works when the lists differ in length, you'll need to adjust the function if that's not desired.

Comment: No, a function can also refuse to return an answer when the lists are not of equal length. The original question doesn't ask for equality of lists.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the lists are the same length, you could use the `zip` function

```
for i, j in zip(l1, l2):
    if i == j:
        print '{0} and {1} are equal and in the same position'.format(i, j)
```

What the `zip` function does is something like this:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
l2 = [2, 3, 4]
print zip(l1, l2)
# [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

If you want a function that returns `True` or `False` given an input, you could do this

```
def some_func(your_input, l1, l2):
    return (your_input,)*2 in zip(l1, l2)
```

`(your_input,)` is a one-tuple containing `your_input`, and multiplying it by two makes it `(your_input, your_input)` - which is what you want to test for.

Or if you want the return `True` if any satisfy the condition

```
def some_func(l1, l2):
    return any(i == j for i, j in zip(l1, l2))
```

The `any` function basically checks if any of the elements of a list (or in this case a generator) are `True` in a boolean context, so in this case it returns true if two lists satisfy your condition.

Comment: This is perfect thanks, can I ask what the .format(i,j) does?

Comment: Thanks for copying my answer into yours, really shows character.

Comment: @Ricochet_Bunny it's string formatting. Basically you give it parameters which it basically replaces the stuff in the `{}` in. The numbers tell `format` what to put in place of the braces.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I didn't mean it like that. I was just reading your answer, and I thought, I had already talked about a function for a given input, why not give a function that returned `True` if *any* index satisfied the condition? After all the previous function led perfectly on to this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want a method to compare one position in two lists you can use the following:

```
def compare_pos(l1, l2, pos):
    try:
        return l1[pos] == l2[pos]
    except IndexError:
        return False

l1 = [0, 1, 2, 3]
l2 = [0, 2, 2, 4]

for i, _ in enumerate(l1):
    print i, compare_pos(l1, l2, i)

# Output:
# 0 True
# 1 False
# 2 True
# 3 False
```

If you want to test whether two lists have all the same elements in the same positions you can just check for equality:

```
print l1 == l2
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd get common elements from both lists:

```
l1 = [a, b, c, d]
l2 = [e, b, f, g]
common_elements = [(i, v) for i,v in enumerate(l1) if l2[i] == v]
```

This will create a list of tuples: `(index, value)` and then you can just check if your desired value or index is in the list.